# Play a music file in C++ program being compiled by MinGW

Tags: c++, c, mingw

I'm using the minGW compiler to make a C++ program that plays a song file in loop in the background for a game. I pass this into the command prompt  : `D:\project g++ music.cpp`

And the error I get is:

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5qzuQ.o:music.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `PlaySoundA@12'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

What am I doing wrong? I can't find any clear explanation for this for minGW (not visual studio). Any help is appreciated!!

The code is:

````
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
  PlaySound(TEXT("blue.wav"), NULL, SND_SYNC);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}```
````

Comment: [`PlaySound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85)) is a part of the `Winmm.lib` library, which you need to somehow include in your project.

Comment: Did you consider installing [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.com/) or [Debian](http://debian.org/) on your computer? Then you could use [Qt](http://qt.io/)

Comment: This: `c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:` suggests a Linux operating system, but `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQ5qzuQ.o:music.cpp:` is a Windows path.  What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using a windows 10 pc, I am using command prompt to pass in those commands @ryyker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "undefined reference to `PlaySoundA` suggests that you are not including the right library into your project. It requires: Mmsystem.h (include Windows.h) Winmm.lib Winmm.dll.

[read more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85))

Steps to add a library in Code::Blocks are:

- Choose Project, Build Options.
- Click the Linker Settings tab. Click the Add button. ...
- Select the library file and click the Open button. Click No to avoid using a relative path.
- Click OK to add the library to the list. ...
- Choose File, Save Project.

Make sure the .dll is included in your path environment variable.